# How do you execute a subset of JUnit tests using Ant?

Tags: java, ant, junit

We have a large project and executing all our unit tests takes a lot of time. We are also using Ant. What strategies could be used to execute only a subset of our tests using Ant? We have our tests in groups of logical java packages, so that could be of help...

Answer (score 1):

You should use `batchtest` tag of the junit ant task. Check here : http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/junit.html

A simplified example from that link is given below:

```
<junit printsummary="yes" haltonfailure="yes">
  <classpath>
    <pathelement location="${build.tests}"/>
    <pathelement path="${java.class.path}"/>
  </classpath>

  <formatter type="plain"/>


  <batchtest fork="yes" todir="${reports.tests}">
    <fileset dir="${src.tests}">
      <include name="**/*Test*.java"/>
      <exclude name="**/AllTests.java"/>
    </fileset>
  </batchtest>
</junit>
```

Comment: Hi. I am actually currently using the batchtest tag, and including some tests and excluding others. However, this means that to createdifferent test profiles, I would need to create many different ant targets? Andthat doesnt sound like therightway to do this...